# Android Play video through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-videoview, launching-application

I created my own media player application and install in a device.
I created an other application which has a single button, As soon as i click on button. I should give an option in which player it should play the video.

Manifest file of my media player application:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.player.MainPlayerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="rtsp" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg4" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/mp4" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/3gp" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/3gpp" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/3gpp2" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/webm" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/avi" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/x-ms-wmv" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/x-msvideo" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/mpeg" />
         </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
            !-- HTTP live support -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/x-mpegurl" />
            <data android:mimeType="audio/mpegurl" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpegurl" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Sample Code for raising an Intent:

```
public class MainActivityHsl extends Activity {
private String url = "/sdcard/vid.mp4";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_hsl);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            playVideo(MainActivityHsl.this, Uri.parse("/sdcard/vid.mp4"), "SUKESH");
        }
    });
} 

public void playVideo(Activity activity, Uri uri, String title) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}}
```

Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime( 1552): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/sdcard/vid.mp4 typ=video/mp4 (has extras) }
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.example.videohsltest.MainActivityHsl.playVideo(MainActivityHsl.java:54)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.example.videohsltest.MainActivityHsl$1.onClick(MainActivityHsl.java:30)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:6073)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:5586)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2575)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:5500)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1246)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1361)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1806)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3327)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2460)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 1552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   W/ActivityManager(  203):   Force finishing activity com.example.videohsltest/.MainActivityHsl

Can Any one please help me out of this, i am not able to launch the complete action using dialog pop up. What is the reason it may be. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how [Dolphin Player](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/source/browse/p/AndroidManifest.xml) does it.

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.player.MainPlayerActivity"" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
                    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*"  />
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-quicktimeplayer*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/x-mpeg" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.dvd*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.3gp*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/3gpp*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.rn-realmedia*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/mp4*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/mpeg*" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/sdp" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*mkv" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MKV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*flv" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*FLV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*wmv" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*WMV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*ts" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*TS" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*rm" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*RM" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*rmvb" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*RMVB" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*webm" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*WEBM" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*mov" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MOV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*mpg" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MPG" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*dat" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*DAT" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*vstream" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*VSTREAM" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*mpeg" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*MPEG" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*f4v" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*F4V" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*avi" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*AVI" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*ogv" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*OGV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*dv" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*DV" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*divx" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*DIVX" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*vob" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*VOB" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*asf" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*ASF" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*3gp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3GP" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*3gpp" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*3GPP" />      

    <data android:pathPattern=".*h264" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*H264" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*h261" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*H261" />

    <data android:pathPattern=".*h263" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*H263" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You can remove the unnecessary media formats that your player does not support.

Comment: Thanks for replying, this i have added into my media player but i am not able to launch it. It is returning the same exception

Comment: Can you add just this intent-filter and remove all other filters and try once more?

Comment: It is returning same exception.